# Best method of continuously collecting data from an API?

Tags: python, api, vps, python-multithreading, data-science

So I have a python script that is continuously collecting data from APIs and then periodically (e.g. every minute) saves them to an excel file. For this I have a VPS running the code 24/7. As I need data from multiple sources and they need to be updated at different frequencies, my solution was creating a separate function for each type of data, and then calling all of them in separate threads.

As an example here's one of them:

```
def ExchangeRateCheck(self):
    while True:
        try:
            self.exchangeRate = self.oanda.get_prices(instruments="AUD_USD").get('prices')[0]['ask']
        except:
            try:
                self.exchangeRate = requests.get('http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=AUD_USD').json()['results']['AUD_USD']['val']
            except:
                pass

        time.sleep(30)

ratethread = threading.Thread(target=self.ExchangeRateCheck, args=())
ratethread.daemon = True
ratethread.start()
```

To account for the times when the API can't be reached, everything is nested in try/except clauses. What I found however is that some threads still end up exiting at some point for some unknown reason.

My questions are:
For this type of task is using a remote VPS and separate functions in a while True loop the best solution? Is there a better way to collect data 24/7? Could I handle the exceptions better to ensure the code never stops running?

As you can probably tell I'm not a professional developer so any feedback is highly appreciated, feel free to go hard on me I won't get offended.

Comment: Your welcome. Daemon threads are just telling the interpreter that if the main thread exits, it's ok to just end the process, instead of waiting for all of the other threads to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the "best" way? That depends. Honestly you could get away with doing all of this in a single thread, though times would vary slightly because of the time it takes to make http requests.

I do have a few things to note, however:

- You are using a try / except, which is good, but you aren't specifically accepting any specific errors, which is kind of bad. You should specify which errors you want to accept (such as ones for not being able to reach the server, invalid json content, etc).
  Remember that you can also except any unknown errors, and do something else with them, like this:

  try:
      do_something_here()
  except MadeUpError as e:
      print("Handled the made up error.")
  except Exception as e:
      Print("Something unexpected happened: {}".format(e))
- You are using daemon threads. Daemon threads allow the program to exit without stopping them first. This means if your main thread exits, the entire program should as well. I don't think this is what you want, and since your program runs for more than just a second and then exits, I'm assuming you are doing something in the main thread. Is there a specific reason your data retrieval workers are daemons?
- You don't have an easy way to stop the program. Instead of using `while True:`, you could use a threading.Event. This is a flag that the main thread can set when, say, it wants all of the workers to exit. The main thread can run a try / except for KeyboardInterrupt, and in the except handler you can .set() that event, telling the workers to exit when they have finished doing what they are currently doing.
- If you find yourself needing more complex scheduling (maybe one worker needs to execute every 30 seconds, another every 5 minutes, another every day at 12:30 AM), you might consider using a library such as [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/), which is specifically designed to run functions at certain times, with intervals, and supports different schedulers (though you'll probably want backgroundScheduler, which uses threads).
- You aren't using any kind of logging or printing to the screen that I can see. For something that's going to run for a long time and might encounter errors that you will want to know about later, it's generally a good idea to log. Python has a nice logging module that comes with the standard library, and it has a tutorial on how to use it as well. You can send log messages to the terminal, a file, via email, etc. There are different logging levels, so you can set your program to, say, only print warnings and above to the terminal, while debug and info messages won't get printed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the detailed reply! APScheduler seems very useful so I'll have a look into that. The main reason I'm using daemon threads is because I don't ever want to stop them from running unless I stop them (I have KeyboardInterrupt in the main thread). The main function is not really doing anything it is basically while True: sleep(120), it's only there to make sure the script never stops running. This method seems very unpythonic to me though, and I'm sure there's a better solution to keep everything running forever.

Answer (score 0):

Consider simplifying it even more by externalizing the scheduling part. You could use cron to run your script at various intervals and with different parameters (i.e. the data source URL). This way you can avoid problems with programming concurrency yourself.